# OSGi Bundle Installation Bootstrapping

Tags: osgi

I am reading "OGSi in Action" where in an interesting comment has been made :

"The module layer uses the metadata in bundles to make sure all their dependencies are satisfied before they can be used. This symbiotic relationship creates a chicken-and-egg situation when you want to use your bundles; to use a bundle you have to install it, but to
install a bundle you must have a bundle context, which are only given to bundles."

The book goes to great length in explaining bundle dependency resolution , but the "chicken and egg" scenario described above hasnt really been explored further. To install a bundle , BundleContext is needed, which is only provided to bundles. So who created the first "bootstrapping" bundle ? Is this contained in the "shells" that are provided (using packageAdmin?) ? PackageAdmin has 
Bundle getBundle(Class clazz);

and Bundle can provide the BundleContext, but the bundle has to be installed first ... and so on !!
How does this work ?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Framework Launching API](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/launch/package-summary.html) which provides the launcher with access to the system bundle's Bundle Context to install the "first" bundles.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of *Bundle.getBundleContext()*:

> If this bundle is not in the STARTING, ACTIVE, or STOPPING states or
>   this bundle is a fragment bundle, then this bundle has no valid
>   BundleContext. This method will return null if this bundle has no
>   valid BundleContext.

I do not know what the writer of the book thought about. If you install a bundle programmatically, you install it via the bundle context of other bundle.

With all my respect, I think this paragraph is wrong. This "chicken and egg" philosophical question could be raised in case of the system bundle. However, I do not think that answering the unnecessary question would give a better understanding for the reader, who wants to get started with OSGi.